# Converting a sum into a vector

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I Have a sum

```
a + b + c + d + ...
```

How can I turn it into the vector

```
{a, b, c, d, ... }
```

Comment: You will want to change the head of your expression from `Plus` to `List`. Try this: `sum = a + b + c + d; List @@ sum`. You could also use a replacement rule `sum /. Plus -> List`.

Comment: note the sum is by default put in canonical order, so `List @@ (c + b + a) -> {a,b,c}`  When you say vector that seems to imply order is important...

Answer (score 2):

```
f = Function[x, Block[{Plus = List}, x], HoldAll]

f @ (c + b + a)
```

> {c, b, a}